# Label for checkbox always nil

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to set label for custom checkbox:
https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox
It have method `(UILabel *)titleLabel`, but when I'm trying to set it like this

```
label = UILabel()
label.text = "testText"
checkbox.titleLabel = label
```

I got error

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: Why are you assigning a label? It should be created by M13. You should just be able to do `checkbox.titleLabel.text = "testText"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the title text then

> (UILabel *)titleLabel: The title label will appear if one sets a
>   string for it to display. The label will fill the control's frame
>   minus the frame of the checkbox itself.

```
yourCheckbox.titleLabel.text = "Your Text Here"
```

There are three methods in class to initialize with title

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title checkHeight:(CGFloat)checkHeight;
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I got same error. Maybe I should call constructor, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the following constructor maybe?

```
 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

Answer (score 0):

`titleLabel` is a getter method, meaning that it *returns* an object, you cannot set a label on the checkbox this way.

You will need to set the text of the label directly:

```
checkbox.titleLabel.setText("testText")
```